# what dbms should I use?

Tags: database

I have do create a small application that needs a database.
core features:

this db will be stored on a nas.
multi user support. 
SQL.

I will probably use c#.

which dbms do you think is the best for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server.

Similar question have been asked many times

you can find your answer here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757820/c-sharp-mysql-vs-microsoft-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1757885/5740382)

[Which database would you recommend to use with C# (.NET) application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174059/which-database-would-you-recommend-to-use-with-c-sharp-net-application)

[Choosing Database and ORM for a .NET project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238972/choosing-database-and-orm-for-a-net-project)

[What NoSQL solutions are out there for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net)